# Migration from Exchange 2003 to Postfix

Tags: postfix, migration, ms-exchange

I need to know if there is an easy way or a program that will migrate old mailboxes on exchange 2003 sbs, into a new postfix mailbox? What is the easiest way of doing this? The exchange 2003 mailboxes will only need to be a copy put into a folder of the new postfix mailbox. Since the old exchange will be retired.

Comment: `imaptools` is a collection of perl scripts to synchronize/copy mails from/to different mail systems. Take a look at http://www.athensfbc.com/imap_tools/, especially for `imap_to_maildir.pl` and `IMAPtoMbox.pl`.

Comment: I am more looking for a way to copy the mailbox from exchange and put it into the store folder of postfix. Is there a way to do this? I would need step by step instructions and hopefully pictures to help.

Comment: postfix itself has no `store folder`; it is just an MTA (Mail Transport Agent). Postfix has different methods of receiving mail (e.g. SMTP) and different methods to deliver mail (e.g. SMTP). The only kind of store is when postfix delivers mail to lokal mailbox; in this case the mailbox may be in `maildir` format. To have mail fetched by clients, you need POP3 or IMAP4 protocol, which is e.g. provided by `dovecot`or `cyrus`. If you only want to copy the mails from exchange to a lokal maildir, `imap_to_maildir.pl` is the tool to use. http://www.athensfbc.com/imap-tools/IMAP_Tools_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: Ridgy the way the postfix is currently setup is imap to new server. Is there a way to copy the old mailboxes without connecting to old server? I can connect users pc to old mail server. Kinda like export pst. And import it into the users folder. But I want to just copy the mailboxes into a folder on users new postfix mailbox.

Comment: Mailboxes in MS Exchange are sort of databases. You can not access them without the server running. This implies security (even the administrator is not able to read mails of other users), as far as  know - maybe MS Exchange professionals would know another way, but you'ld have to ask that in an other community.

Comment: So to make sure we're both on the same page here is what I am trying to do. I want to take a copy of mailbox A (exchange 2003) and import it into a folder of mailbox B  (postfix) is there a step by step way of doing this? Without having to connect old exchange to new post. The ways I can access old server is through users computer with Outlook and owa or accessing old exchange server directly these are the ways I would export the mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Exchange expert, nor have I a lot of knowledge on MS software. But as far as I know (and others may know better), using the native Exchange protocols is only possible with MS software like Outlook. I did not find a way to export mailboxes this way except for creating .pst files (se e.g. [Exchange Mailbox Backup](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/exchange-mailbox-backup-pst-pros-cons/)). There are tools to export to IMAP servers like `courier` via Outlook (see e.g. [Converting all your Mailboxes](https://www.howtoforge.com/converting_outlook_pst_to_maildir)), but that needs you to install `courier-imap` (or any other IMAP server) somewhere.

If you want to have your Exchange mailboxes exported directly to a local `mailbox`folder structure, the easiest way is to use the IMAP protocol, as Exchange is able to support that.

If you have access to Exchange and the necessary administration rights, enable IMAP in Exchange Server (see [Enable IMAP4 in Exchange](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124489(v=exchg.150).aspx)). Then on any PC/host with `perl`language installed (not necessary your postfix server; preferrable LINUX OS) you may use the [IMAP-Tools](http://www.athensfbc.com/imap_tools/) as I stated in previous comments. For more info, read the [Documentation](http://www.athensfbc.com/imap-tools/IMAP_Tools_User_Guide.pdf), especially chapter 4.1 and 4.9.

Of course, in all those cases, you need to know the usernames/passwords of the users, or with some tools an administrative account in Exchange with Import/Export rights. And be prepared to invest some time; it's not that easy as it reads.

Comment: Ridgy is there a way I can contact you directly in real time instead of emails? Like chat or phone.

Comment: Sorry, I am on the road most of the time. I'd suggest you find someone near to you having some expertise in MS Exchange; this is the most complicated part when trying to copy mailboxes. And the only way I know of I have tried to illustrate in my answer.

Comment: Could you give me an outline with photos please?